# Formula to compute no. of threads of any program

Tags: multithreading

Is there a particular way to compute how much threads will give optimal performance as per no. of cores in the system, hyper threading, ram and other system requirements.

For e.g. a simple formula would be

```
No. of Threads = (No. of Cores) * 2 + ......
```

But this is not optimal as there as hyper threading environments which provides extra support for threading.

Which things can we consider to get no. of thread counts based on system.

If my application is going to be deployed on multiple platforms of different unknown configuration it is very necessary to know the no. of threads which we can create.

Comment: Profiling is the way to go. Formula's can be a good rough estimate, but from there, and per system, you need to do profiling to get true information.

Comment: Actually I have a client which installs on each client machine having different configuration and I cannot profile it, so I am looking for some formula which will calculate the no. of threads. If the formula is correct to 80% then also it will suffice my needs. I am not looking for 100% efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks offer a `ThreadPool`-like class, specifically designed to overcome this issue (and others). Assign work items to a threadpool, and let it decide how many threads to spawn.

If the framework you're using has no thread pool, and you want to implement your own, try starting with a simple Hill-Climbing algorithm.
First, decide how to measure the "performance"/"throughput" of your application (e.g., requests/second, problems solved/second, etc). Then:

1. Measure the throughput with the current number of threads (n)
2. Have the pool spawn +1 thread
3. Measure the throughput with n+1 threads
4. If the throughput has increased, go back to step 1; if the throughput has decreased, go back to step 1, but this time shut one thread down, instead of spawning a new one.

Repeat this process periodically until you come to a peak.

Here's some details of how the CLR's ThreadPool is implemented: [Throttling Concurrency in the CLR 4.0 ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx)